# peewee ArrayField of UUIDS

Tags: python, postgresql, uuid, peewee

I am trying to manipulate, using peewee, a table which has a column containing an array of uuids.

The model is the following:

```
class test_db(BaseModel):
    arr = playhouse.postgres_ext.ArrayField(
        peewee.UUIDField,
        index_type=False
    )
```

I would like to insert an entry into this table and I am using the following code:

```
arr = [uuid.UUID('d167169e-a017-4c17-8f3a-1dee98c1e563')]

x = test_db(arr=arr)
x.save()
```

But I received

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'UUID'
```

I also tried this one

```
arr = ['d167169e-a017-4c17-8f3a-1dee98c1e563']

x = test_db(arr=arr)
x.save()
```

But I received the following error:

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: column "arr" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "test_db" ("arr") VALUES (ARRAY['d167169e-a017-4...
                                              ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Could you please provide some help for this issue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires you to register a UUID type:

```
import psycopg2.extras
psycopg2.extras.register_uuid()
```

With the above code, you should be able to simply use:

```
arr = ArrayField(UUIDField, index=False)
```